# How to Handle Automator Errors with Applescript

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm still pretty much a newbie, so I hope my question makes sense.

I created a simple Automator application. I have iCal set to run it during the night. Because other things are running at the same time, I sometimes get "The action "blah blah blah" encountered an error...."

Is there a way (with Applescript) to either: (1) ignore the error and have the application continue or (2) click the "OK" button on the error and restart the application?

**EDIT:** I basically want Applescript to run the Automator-created app and, if/when that app has a "The action "blah blah blah" encountered an error"-type message, I want Applescript to continue or restart the Automator-created app. This includes getting rid of the error message box that popped up during the running of the Automator-created app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is within an Applescript, you can try something like this:

```
repeat with i from 1 to 5
    try
        --insert your code here
        set thrownError to 1 / 0

        -- If code completes without error, exit repeat
        exit repeat
    on error
        beep
        delay 3
    end try
end repeat
```

Comment: Sorry, the code isn't in Applescript. The app was created in Automater (basically multiple Watch Me Dos & loops). Whenever something delays what the app is doing, I get the "encountered an error" message. I basically get the error when my computer is trying to do multiple things. I'm looking for a way to use Applescript to eliminate the popup error msg and restart the Automater-created app whenever this timeout-like error occurs. Thanks again.

Comment: Try to drag the actions from Watch me do into the workflow which will create an Applescript to enclose in the try block.

Comment: @adayzdone, oh that's interesting! user2475147, You could try setting the timeout to a higher level.  The duration of the timeout is a setting in the "Watch Me Do" action.  Anyways, also, here is a link to a page on GUI Scripting: http://www.learnbymac.com/wiki/index.php?title=GUI_Scripting#External_Links

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to ignore an error in applescript, just use `try`

```
try
  --do what ever
on error
  --continue with code
end
```